# Driving MOSFETs for flexibility

Tags: microcontroller, mosfet, control, control-system, mosfet-driver

I designed a circuit to drive high-powered devices.

These devices are mainly a 24 V, 3 A LED bar, high-powered relays (24 V, 30 A) and a DC motor (12 V, 30 A) in my lab.

The low-side gate driver I chose is the [UCC27517DBVR](https://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/UCC27517) and it will be controlled by a microcontroller. The LED bar and the motor will both be driven with PWM and the relay as a switch.

One of my concerns was the choice of MOSFET I made, the [RD3G400GN](https://fscdn.rohm.com/en/products/databook/datasheet/discrete/transistor/mosfet/rd3g400gntl-e.pdf), knowing that it only dissipates 26 W and that the V<sub>GS</sub> optimal for a low R<sub>DS(on)</sub> is 10 V and full current of I<sub>D</sub> = 40 A.

Basically I'd like to get feedback to know if these circuits need to be modified or if they are over-engineered for the purpose of device control and flexibility.

Comment: Hi, welcome! Your question can be improved with additional information: which is it, motor or relay? The relay coil will not draw anywhere near 30A. A driver as strong as UCC27517 isn't needed (you're drawing max 12mA from it as shown!); if you need 12V gate drive, you might consider a level shifter like CD4504, or use a discrete circuit. RD3G400GN is also rated for logic level input, and it will switch faster driven from the MCU pin (through a smaller resistance say 100 ohms).

Comment: @TimWilliams Thank you for your feedback. Currently I made a mistake because the objective is to be able to supply the 10 V to the gate of the MOSFET as this allows to have the current ID = 40 A .. which is the parameter sought when controlling the DC motor . The main reason for adding the UCC27517 is to provide flexibility of operation when controlling PWM equipment. In the schematic, I put the symbol of the relay, indeed.  I should adjust the Req so that I can draw at least the 4A from the Low side gate driver.

Comment: Also thanks for the edit!

Comment: I would remove C1 as you are charging and discharging it every PWM cycle. You probably wanted it connected between +12V and GND, not the FETs drain.

Comment: What's D1, X4 for? They will draw quite a lot of current from the driver if you reduce R1/R3. Running Vgs(on) above 10V is perfectly fine, as long as you're under the max rating. The main downside from higher voltages is the higher drive power loss.

Comment: @TimWilliams Thanks Tim,  X1 and D1 are mainly used to clamp the voltage slightly above 10V to maintain the optimal Rds also they serve as a path for high current discharge from the MOSFET above the sink capacity of the low side gate driver

Comment: That's not how MOSFETs work; gate current is drawn as the voltage changes, it's capacitive (I = C dV/dt). Just connect driver to gate with a series resistor, nothing else needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Analysis:** Based on the Datasheets [Datasheet MOSFET](https://fscdn.rohm.com/en/products/databook/datasheet/discrete/transistor/mosfet/rd3g400gntl-e.pdf) and [Datasheet Driver](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ucc27517.pdf?ts=1673336709251&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FUCC27517) you can only use the above circuit at 18V max (limited by the VCC-Path of the Driver): So if your intent to use it with your 24V-Loads (V1 and V2=24V) there is a problem. On the other hand: If V1 and V2 are +12V and the Loads are fed from a different source: All fine in this respect.

**Also:** There my be an issue on your PWM-FET as the 1K Resistor acts as a RC-Lowpass in combination with the Diode and the FET Gate capacitance. So you PWM-frequency will be limited and your switching Time (Time of highest loss in FET) will be increased. This will increase you power loss.
But it also defeats the purpose of the Driver itself. By using the 1K series resistor, you are limiting your drive current to around Vgs,max/1K= 12V/1k = 12mA. Far from the 4A possible. This will increase your switch-over time drastically.

I would recommend using a 5Ohm series resistor without voltage divider. The Vgs is max 20V so you are good here.

**Also:** With around 10mOhm max RDSON (Figure 12, added some extra) you can expect static losses by the formula: Rdsin * Ids * Ids; This gives you ~10W max for the 30A devices (Motor and Relay - does the relay really take 30A in through the coil? Or, are you driving the motor via the relay?). Based on [Thermal Resistance Data: TO252-3](https://fscdn.rohm.com/en/products/databook/applinote/ic/power/linear_regulator/to252-3_rth_bd4xxm5fp_an-e.pdf) Figure 14 there might be a problem (See O Junction<->Ambient ~ 100°C/W when assuming 100mm^2 top foil. You will need to use a good cooling solution. Dissipating ~10W in a safe, effective and "small" ways is not that easy as it sounds.

**Also:** As you want to connect you logic signal from an external device, a 1KOhm series resistor in the signal path can provide a bit of "ESD" protection. You can add a small TVS-Diode as well. The Devices have a 230kOhm internal Pulldown on the IN+ pin.

**Recommendations:**
My recommendations are based on some assumptions, as your question has some "red-flags". They are also based on the comments on your question.

1. I guess your Relay wont draw 30A through the coil.
2. You don't want to rive the motor directly. Rather you intend to do: MCU->Gadget->Relay->Motor

This reduces your design criteria too: Low-Side switch 24V/3A max (LED-Bar) via PWM. The Relay circuit can be driven in this configuration as well.

I would choose a "logic-level" N-FET with an RDson < 20mOhm @ Vgs 4V and Vds,max 40V. This reduces your power requirements to around 200mW (20mOhm, 3A). So no worries here.

I would drive these FETs from a simple Schmitt-trigger gate (powered from the Arduino 5V-Rail) with a Driver->R->FET Gate resistance of ~ 10Ohm. I would also add a signal series resistor and a TVS-Diode on the input. I would keep the Diode on the FET-Gate, but make sure it is a low capacitance one. I would also keep the back-EMF diode across the load: Well done! And then a LED on the Input-Signal and Vcc's (5V logic and Load) - just for the feedback.

**EDIT 1:**
I just read, that you want to drive the motor directly. In this case I would still go with a "Logic-level" FET. If you want to PWM your Motor: Keep the frequencies low (few 100 Hz tops. The motor inertia will work as PT1, so no use in switching it faster.)

BUT: Ids>30A is not that easy. Keep an eye on your power Dissipation. Assuming Rdson 10mOHm (Doable with a logic-level FET rate for these currents) there are ~10W to get rid off. These are the static losses, only when PWM is "on". So Pstat= 10W*Duty-Cyle. On top of that there are dynamic losses when PWMing a FET as the switch over crosses the Linear/Non-Linear operation modes. Basically: Your VDS gets higher, but your current is still substantial. So PDyn = Integral(Uds(t)*Ids(t))dt over the switching period.

Have a carefully look ate the thermal design guide i added as link. You want to keep your TJunction below lets say 100°C (You can go higher, but 100°C is a good design criteria, as there are always losses you did not consider during the designphase).

Comment: Thank you for you analysis, it was really helpful. I changed the value of R1 and R3 to 3 ohms and choose a tvs diode with lower capacitance 0.5 pF. Also to reduce Pd of this design I bought a DC motor with lower amps which changes the power consumption of the MOSFET in regards off the thermal data characteristic. Now Pd is 7.5 mohms * 20A = 3W. As it is below  the limit of 10 W, it should be good now. Still think I might need some sort of heat sink.

Comment: @Wyufiyra Yes, sounds like it. You can google "Thermal Resistance" of your package. Then take Junction-To-Case value. Then choose a appropriate Heatsink. Look for the thermal resistance again. Add these two values. Multiplie with your Powerloss -> Gives you the Junction Temperator. E.G. 15°C/W Junction-To-Case, 10°C/W for the Heatsink -> 25°C/W * 3W  = 75°C above ambient (e.g. 40°C max) -> 125°C TJunction max. Stay within reasonable limits here (E.g. design for TJunction of 100°C with T-Ambient 40°C -> gives you a lot of headroom)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to PWM some LEDs or a motor, there is no point in switching the MOSFET at hundreds of kHz. In fact it would be a bad idea, because that would increase switching losses.

To reduce switching losses at a high switching frequency, fast switching is required, which creates lots of high frequency harmonics and turns wires into antennas. Essentially, if you're using a MOSFET driver for its intended purpose, which is to switch the FET in a couple tens of ns, you'll probably make a wideband radio jammer unless you take great care with filtering.

So it is much simpler to use a low switching frequency.

For LEDs, flicker is a problem if switching frequency is too low. A good frequency is 5 kHz. If your power supply makes an audible whine at this frequency when loaded with PWM current you can increase it to 25 kHz, it's also fine. The point is, you can switch the MOSFET slowly, say in 1-2µs, and it'll be fine.

For the motor, you could switch at a few kHz.

For the relay, I have trouble believing it draws 30A on the coil. Most likely this is the contact rating, and the relay coil draws much less current. And you're not going to PWM it.

If you already have 5V available, for LEDs the ideal is to use a MOSFET with 5V gate drive. Then the driver can be a simple 74HCT chip to convert 3V3 signals from the microcontroller into 5V. The low output current helps with slowing down switching. There are lots of adequate MOSFETs for this, aim for RdsON such that it will not need a heat sink.

For the motor, due to the high current, you will need very low RdsON to keep dissipation low. Note the "power dissipation" number in the MOSFET datasheet comes with a footnote that says "* at Tc=25°C" so this number is only valid with a large heat sink, which you cannot mount on the mentioned SMD MOSFET. It's SMD, so unless your board is specially designed and coupled to a heat sink with squishy pads, or it's a metal core PCB, it won't be able to dissipate more than 2W if the PCB is the heat sink.

The 7 mOhms MOSFET will dissipate a lot more, so this is not adequate. If you want to use SMD MOSFETs, you can simply pick lower RdsON ones and use several in parallel, which spreads the dissipation over a larger PCB area, or you could use a TO-220 MOSFET on a small heatsink. This has the advantage of higher thermal mass, so it will cope better with the motor starting current. In any case, it is better to get a MOSFET with a very low RdsON, as that will save money and bulk on the heat sink. If the MOSFET requires 10-12V gate drive, then you'll need an extra voltage regulator to make this voltage from 24V.

To drive it, you can use a driver, but you will need a gate resistor to keep switching slow enough to avoid EMI.

Note the diode must be rated to carry the whole motor current. Worst case would be when ramping up the PWM to start the motor. The diode will dissipate quite a lot of power, and a TO-220 schottky diode on the same heat sink as the MOSFET would be a better choice.

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice.
I took them down for my test phase when ordering the various equipment. Since your advice is empirical, I would pay attention to the optimal switching time for the motor and the led bar. Also The micro controller transmits the 5V directly to its output. The reason for using this driver is also the fact that I can isolate the microntroller from the power circuit.

Comment: Your comments on the dissipated power were useful to me.  I changed the DC motor and dimensioned the circuit on a maximum capacity of 20 A. With the resistance value between the drain and the source of 7.5 mOhms * (20A)^2  is gives a Pd of 3W. With 3W, the mosfet is safe from overheating. However, I still think I need a heatsink.

Comment: By the value of the junctions thermal resistance which is 4.8°C/W, I arrived at a possible temperature of 39.4°C ... this value comes from the calculation [ (4.8°C/W *3 W) + 25°C ]. Although this temperature respects the operating range, I am preparing to use a heatsink for the pcb.

Thank you very much for your advice!

Comment: Yes, thermal resistance "junction to case" of 4.8°C/W results in the chip being 14.4°C hotter than the PCB, but that doesn't say how hot the PCB is. Circuit boards are not very good heatsinks because the copper is quite thin and they're usually horizontal. Here's an [appnote](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/snva419c/snva419c.pdf). You would need a very large copper area dedicated to cool the MOSFET. Is 20A the motor starting current or the motor running current?